# HashMap object passed to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, dictionary, hashmap

I am passing a HashMap object to a JavaScript function. The map is created in the JSP using <% > tags provided by struts.
I need to iterate the HashMap key=value pair in the javascript function. How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide some sort of detail about what is actually getting passed to the JavaScript. How are you creating this HashMap? What is this code between your mystical "<% > tags"?

Answer (score 0):

you can't really.  you would need to create a javascript array (or object literal) based of the values in the Java `HashMap`.  You could use a scriptlet to do that

```
var ary = [
// scriptlet here that writes out whatever you want...
];
```

You'd probably be better off requesting a url that returns the HashMap contents as json.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSONObject instead of HashMap. You can directly pass JSONObject to JavaScript and vice versa.